# Changing the css property of id to class

Tags: css

I read that in CSS, the properties of an ID attribute can only be applied to one specific thing referencing it, and if i want to use it on multiple things in a single page, i should use class instead. But the problem is, i'm trying to use the text editor in multiple textarea(s). But the texteditor's property is being applied to id. So when i put only one textarea it works, but not on the second and next..

The code for the texteditor i downloaded from somewhere and i can't seem to find the css to be able to shift the property from originally belonging to id, to a class. So what can i do? Can anyone help suggest me any way?

Comment: Give us an idea what language you're working in, alongside the css. Make a plunker, jsfiddle, or whatever online editor you prefer with a working example of your code please, and I'm sure there's plenty of people who would relish a question such as this.

Comment: Why can't you use a Class (for common properties) and an ID (for the ones unique to each textarea).

Comment: @Chiwda That's why i thought of changing the property from id to class, but there is no css file for that. I couldn't find any css file, only javascript file for the texteditor.

Answer (score 2):

just add a div tag around the editor an set the class to the div tag. Then you do not apply your css style to ".myClass" but to ".myClass textarea"

that should do the trick

good luck

Comment: But the thing is, the way to apply the texteditor is <textarea id="tinymce_basic" name="Message"></textarea> What should i do now? Because it seemed like the texteditor is only for id in textarea.

Comment: is your problem to assign css styles or the texteditor itself?

Comment: to apply tinymce to all textareas: `tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });`
to apply it to a textearea with a given id: `tinymce.init({ selector: '#givenId'});`
to apply it to a class (and therefor to multiple but not all textareas):
`tinymce.init({ selector: '.yourCssClassName' }`